# React Native Storage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, local-storage

A while ago I made an app using React Native and was not able to store data like `token` and `user ID` for future use. Currently I am making a Point transaction app in React Native using Expo and was wondering if there is a way of storing required data to all the pages just like the web has a `localStorage`.

App Functionality:

Users can login to their account and the response has the `token`, `user ID`, `user Name` and `member No`. On the dashboard it shows points gained, redeemed and points available.

Still on the dashboard it can show the last five transactions and if one is clicked, it navigates to a transaction details page which its API requires the `token`, `user ID` and `member No`.

A profile page to edit user details or logout.

I was able to achieve all that by passing those details as route params but after adding a bottom tab navigation the app crashed since `stack Navigator` differs from `Tab Navigation`.

P.S. I have tried Async Storage but the app requires a page refresh to get those data (ie. `token`, `id`, `memberNo`)

Comment: Have you considered looking into [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)? This package allows you to store data on top level and make it accessible for every component (global data store). It also uses `actions` and `reducers`, so each action can be pushed and immediately available for every component that needs to receive the storage data.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand what you want is to be able to share the AsyncStorage values with the rest of your application, for cases in which you want to share states (such as tokens or values of a user's identity) use parameters navigation becomes deficient and uncomfortable to use when wanting to send states or state values from a higher level to a lower one, even more so in large applications that already have many layers. For this you have two options, the use of Redux to make it easy to access your data throughout your application, or you can also use the useRef hook which is a quick output that is already plugged into the react native libraries [useRef hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)